# How to create nested category list from category-strings in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table "products" that has a column called "category". In this field you find the categorie herarchy for every product as a string. E.g.:

```
female / dresses / long
female / dresses / short
female / shoes  
male / shoes / sneakers / skate
...
```

I selected all different categories with:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM products ORDER BY category");
```

Now, I want to be able to print these categories as a nested HTML-list like

- female

  - dresses

    - long
    - short
  - shoes
- male

  - shoes

    - sneaker

      - skate

Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I get the data from several csv files, so a solution without the need of transforming the categories would be great!

Comment: I advice to have separate table for categories and read about "Nested sets".

Comment: You need to know who is parent and who is child , and also the depth

Comment: a solution without the need of a second table would be great, since I get the data as csv in this format.

Comment: @AndiPower impossible...

Comment: @AndiPower even if you would find a solution without a second table it would perform terrible bad. So spending the time in preprocessing and using `Nested Tree Sets` like _Sanja_ suggested is the best way to avoid bottlenecks and other problems in future. To make the import easier you can for sure use a _path_ to _node in tree_  mapping as fast lookup table for import, with that it shouldn't be a big deal to implement this even with multiple csv files as source. Here a short description of [Nested Tree Sets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14959883/1960455) I wrote to another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just construct your tree using the categories as the node's key. For example :

```
$categoryLines = array(
    "female / dresses / long",
    "female / dresses / short",
    "female / shoes",
    "male / shoes / sneakers / skate"
);

function buildCategoryTree($categoryLines, $separator) {
    $catTree = array();
    foreach ($categoryLines as $catLine) {
       $path = explode($separator, $catLine);
       $node = & $catTree;
       foreach ($path as $cat) {
           $cat = trim($cat);
           if (!isset($node[$cat])) {
               $node[$cat] = array();
           }
           $node = & $node[$cat];
       }
    }
    return $catTree;
}

function displayCategoryTree($categoryTree, $indent = '') {
    foreach ($categoryTree as $node => $children) {
        echo $indent . $node . "\n";
        displayCategoryTree($children, $indent . '|- ');
    }
}

$categoryTree = buildCategoryTree($categoryLines, '/');
```

Now, `var_export($categoryTree)` will output :

```
array (
  'female' => array (
    'dresses' => array (
      'long' => array (),
      'short' => array (),
    ),
    'shoes' => array (),
  ),
  'male' => array (
    'shoes' => array (
      'sneakers' => array (
        'skate' => array (),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

and `displayCategoryTree($categoryTree)` will output :

```
female
|- dresses
|- |- long
|- |- short
|- shoes
male
|- shoes
|- |- sneakers
|- |- |- skate
```

#### ** Edit **

To get the HTML representation of the tree :

```
function displayHtmlCategoryTree($categoryTree, $id = null, $pathSeparator = '/', $parents = '') {
    if (empty($categoryTree)) return '';

    $str = '<ul' . (!empty($id) ? ' id="'.$id.'"' : '') . '>';
    foreach ($categoryTree as $node => $children) {
        $currentPath = $parents . (empty($parents) ? '' : $pathSeparator) . $node;
        $str .= '<li title="' . $currentPath . '">' . $node . 
                displayHtmlCategoryTree($children, null, $pathSeparator, $currentPath) . 
                '</li>';
    }
    $str .= '</ul>';
    return $str;
}

echo displayHtmlCategoryTree($categoryTree, "test", ' / ');
```

and will output :

```
<ul id="test"><li title="female">female<ul><li title="female / dresses">dresses<ul><li title="female / dresses / long">long</li><li title="female / dresses / short">short</li></ul></li><li title="female / shoes">shoes</li></ul></li><li title="male">male<ul><li title="male / shoes">shoes<ul><li title="male / shoes / sneakers">sneakers<ul><li title="male / shoes / sneakers / skate">skate</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: Leaves on this tree are `Array`. Think it's better to replace it with a single string.

Comment: Why does it matter? This is actually better since it does not create an exceptions; meaning that leaves or nodes.... they both have the "label" as keys and an array defining any potential children as value. Doing anything other than that requires extra and unncecessary checks.

Comment: I'm not a data structure geek and I don't know what are the consequences of having no leaves in a tree so, I was just mentioning that it'd better to have an ending point in paths. Besides, extra check is just up to look at current node's depth and that's all, no heavy lifting. Cheers :)

Comment: @YanickRochon: That's fantastic. You're my hero and now I feel dumb. The buildCategoryTree-function is very clever. Thanks for the title-elements in the HTML! Great!

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned in comments, you'd better to use `nested tree sets` for this kind of categorization, but since you asked you don't want to change the scheme of your category system and IF and only IF you're not concerned about your run-time overload, you can use this code that I wrote.

For populating an array of categories:

```
<?php
  $rows = array(
    "female/dresses/long",
    "female/dresses/short",
    "female/dresses/short/1",
    "female/dresses/short/2",
    "female/dresses/short/2/1",
    "female/shoes",
    "male/shoes/sneakers/skate"
  );

  $categories = array();

  function populate()
  {
    global $rows;
    global $categories;

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
      $category_array = explode(" / ", $row);

      $categories = place($categories, $category_array);
    }
  }

  function place($categories, $category, $counter = 0)
  {
    if($counter < count($category))
    {
      if(!isset($categories[$category[$counter]]))
      {
        $categories[$category[$counter]] = array();
      }
      else if($counter == count($category) - 1)
      {
        $categories[$category[$counter]][] = $category[$counter];
      }

      // Recurse
      $categories[$category[$counter]] = place($categories[$category[$counter]], $category, $counter + 1);
    }

    return $categories;
  }

  // Populate categories
  populate();
?>
```

You can replace my `foreach` on `$rows` with your fetch `while` loop.

For displaying of categories:

```
<?php
  function display($items)
  {
    foreach($items as $k => $v)
    {
      echo "<li>" . $k;

      if(is_array($v))
      {
        echo "<ul>";

        display($v);

        echo "</ul>";
      }

      echo "</li>";
    }
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Categories</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
  <?php
    // Display categories
    display($categories);
  ?>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Current demonstration:

```
female
    dresses
        long
        short
            1
            2
                1
    shoes

male
    shoes
        sneakers
            skate
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Your solution is good, too. Yanick just hit the bull's eye.

Comment: @AndiPower That's OK. We're here to help each other :)