# MySQL Sorting by parents and children

Tags: mysql, sorting

Here a simple Table:

```
id, title, parent, ordering
---------------------------
3242, TitleB, 0, 1
6574, TitleBA, 3242, 1
2346, TitleBB, 3242, 2
2344, TitleA, 0, 1
7346, TitleAC, 2344, 3
3574, TitleAB, 2344, 2
2256, TitleAA, 2344, 1
1435, TitleC, 0, 1
4354, TitleCA, 1435, 1
```

I'm searching for a query that can order and output these rows like this:

```
TitleA
  TitleAA
  TitleAB
  TitleAC
TitleB
  TitleBA
  TitleBB
TitleC
  TitleCA
```

So the rows should be ordered by the first parent, then followed by its children items ordered. Then the next parent followed followed by its children items and so on.

The ordering of the parents themselves does not matter! The titles are only for better understanding and cannot be used for sorting. The important thing is that the children get sorted under their parents.

This is the last query i did:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
     LEFT JOIN table t2
     ON t2.id = t1.parent 
ORDER BY COALESCE(t1.ordering, t2.ordering), t2.ordering
```

Comment: How about you at least show us your tables?

Comment: you see the table above, right?

Comment: If that's the case simple "ORDER BY title" will do.

Comment: The titles were chosen by me to better understand the example. Of course you can not do an alphabetically sort in real life. That's should be clear.

Comment: Should we just assume what else is chosen by you? How do you know that TitleA should be in front of the TitleB?

Comment: Is it by "id" field?

Comment: do you see the last column called ordering and the example output i posted?

Comment: You changed your answer and updated the id's but the parent field is now pointing to old id's. This just can't work!

Comment: It's still the same. I changed the IDs so people don't try a solution by sorting IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial solution might be the following query:

```
SELECT t.title FROM t GROUP BY IF(parent=0,id,parent), 
IF(parent=0,-1,ordering), t.title ORDER BY IF([parent]=0,
id,parent), IF(parent=0,-1,ordering);
```

Result is like following:

```
TitleC
TitleCC
TitleA
TitleAA
TitleAB
TitleAC
TitleB
TitleBA
TitleBB
```

To indent the header of each group, something like report in MS Access might be used.
I've prepared it in MS Access, so there may be difference slightly in MySQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but the titles were only chosen for better understanding the example. They can totally vary and can't be used for sorting.

Comment: Without title, how do  we know who is whose parent and child? `TitleA`, `TitleB`, `TitleC` have the same `parent` value =0, and the same `ordering`=1.

Comment: look at the id and the parent columns.

Comment: The ordering of the parents doesn't matter. the important thing is that the children get sorted under their parents.

Comment: Has `id` some info about parent-child relation?

Comment: Of course. You see that the ID 2344 has three childs.

Comment: Second digit? `TitleB` is Ok with 2 children.  But why `TitleC` has `id=1435` with only 1 child?

Comment: correct. like you see it in the example output i posted.

Comment: `TitleC` is not correct, because its `id=1435` has the second digit=4, but it has  only 1 child.

Comment: It's fine. Second digit if the id is irrelevant

Comment: I have to say that I cannot understand why `id` defines the number of children, and how to determine these children for each parent without `title`. `parent` and `ordering` don't allow to distinguish `TitleA`,  `TitleB` and `TitleC`.

Comment: The ID does not define the number of the children. The parent defines the belonging and in such the number of children.

Comment: `TitleA`, `TitleB` and `TitleC` have the.same parent=0. How can we determ their children?

Comment: I see. `parent` of child refer to `id of its parent. Sorry for being woody. Start to think about the task.

Comment: What is "IIf"? Does not look like MySQL.

Comment: In some implementaton it is called `if`. In MySQL it is `IF`.
[See manual for detail](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: Square Brackets are also not valid in MySQL

Comment: Sorry, I've prepared it in MS Access. Square brackets stands for reference to table field. Just omit it.

Comment: This actually works...! It does exactly what i was searching for. The query looks really creepy. I thought this could be done in some cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, if(parent = 0, id, parent) as main_order
FROM `tbl`
ORDER by main_order, ordering, parent
```

I think this query correctly work for 1 - parent child.

Solution the same problem see here:
[order sql tree hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890204/order-sql-tree-hierarchy)

Comment: looks interesting, but the ordering is wrong. IDs should not be a search criteria.

Comment: what about this solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890204/order-sql-tree-hierarchy

Comment: Not really. Nested Tree Sets are for unlimited hierarchies and i cant create functions.

Comment: This solution work slowly when insert and update
But work fast when select